# Image does not show up in Wpf Image Control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, system.drawing

I'm re-writing a app of mine, where I create a barcode image using the `Barcode Image Generation Libary` by Brad Barnhill (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20823/Barcode-Image-Generation-Library).

In this article everything is explaned how to do it in Windows Forms. But now - using Wpf - there are some errors. E.g.: The result of the function `Encode`  returns a `System.Drawing.Image` but when I want to display this Image in a `Wpf Image Control` the `Source` property wants a `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`.

So I did some reserach of how to convert a `Drawing.Image` in a `Media.ImageSource`. I found some snippets but they don't work as expected.

Currently I use this code:

```
// Import:
using Media = System.Windows.Media;
using Forms = System.Windows.Forms;


// Setting some porperties of the barcode-object
this.barcode.RotateFlipType = this.bcvm.Rotation.Rotation;
this.barcode.Alignment = this.bcvm.Ausrichtung.Alignment;
this.barcode.LabelPosition = this.bcvm.Position.Position;

// this.bcvm is my BarcodeViewModel for MVVM
var img = this.barcode.Encode(
    this.bcvm.Encoding.Encoding, 
    this.bcvm.EingabeWert, 
    this.bcvm.ForeColor.ToDrawingColor(), 
    this.bcvm.BackColor.ToDrawingColor(), 
    (int)this.bcvm.Breite, 
    (int)this.bcvm.Hoehe
);

this.imgBarcode.Source = img.DrawingImageToWpfImage();

this.imgBarcode.Width = img.Width;
this.imgBarcode.Height = img.Height;

// My conversion methode. It takes a Drawing.Image and returns a Media.ImageSource
public static Media.ImageSource ToImageSource(this Drawing.Image drawingImage)
{
    Media.ImageSource imgSrc = new Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        drawingImage.Save(ms, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        (imgSrc as Media.Imaging.BitmapImage).BeginInit();
        (imgSrc as Media.Imaging.BitmapImage).StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        (imgSrc as Media.Imaging.BitmapImage).EndInit();
    }
    return imgSrc;
}
```

When running this code an converting the image (and assigning it to the Image control) there is nothing displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conversion method should work:

```
public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Position = 0;

        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

In case the `System.Drawing.Image` is actually a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` you may also use some other conversion methods, as shown here: [fast converting Bitmap to BitmapSource wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30727343/1136211)

Comment: thank you clemens! after trying your code I noticed that I just messed up my XAML. the image control was shaddowd by an outer stackpanel-border mix. but your code works as well :D