# BitmapSource rendering glitch due to large width, probable overflow

Tags: .net, wpf, bitmap, integer-overflow, bitmapsource

I've got a bitmap that's 827852 pixels wide by 1 pixel high in a Bitmap object.
When converting the bitmap to a BitmapSource for rendering in WPF, the following artifacts appear in the UI:
[image: An image with a rendering artifact]

The black portion in the middle is not in the original bitmap, and the yellow parts should be green, something like this:
[image: A proper, but zoomed in rendering without artifacts]

By plain old trial and error I've determined that the problem appears when the original bitmap is wider than 524287 pixels. If it's 524288 or larger, I get rendering artifacts after converting it to a BitmapSource. 524287 is 0x7FFFF, which seems to indicate a overflow, but I'm unsure of where.

I'm using the following conversion method:

```
public BitmapSource Convert(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    var bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(
        bitmapData.Width, bitmapData.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null,
        bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height, bitmapData.Stride);

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    return bitmapSource;
}
```

taken from [fast converting Bitmap to BitmapSource wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727343/fast-converting-bitmap-to-bitmapsource-wpf)

Any ideas where the issue occurs and how to work around it? I'm leaning towards rescaling the bitmap to be <524288 pixels manually.

Comment: Did you try any of the other conversion methods, e.g. CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap?

Comment: According to the Remarks section on the [BitmapSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(v=vs.110).aspx) page, the "maximum height and width of an image is 2^16 pixels at 32 bits per channel ..."

Comment: @Clemens Yes, I did, got the same result.

Changing the formats to System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb/ PixelFormats.Bgra32 only serves to make the black part transparent.