# Converting System.Drawing.Image to System.Windows.Media.ImageSource with no result

Tags: c#, wpf, image, type-conversion, imagesource

I would like to convert Image to ImageSource in my WPF app. I use Code128 library which works properly (already checked in WinForms app). Function below returns ImageSource with properly size, but nothing is visible.

```
private ImageSource generateBarcode(string number)
    {
        var image = Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage(number, 1, false);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
The best method is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30729291/1136211). About 4 times faster than using MemoryStream.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` to make sure that the BitmapImage is loaded immediately when `EndInit()` is called. Without that flag, the stream would have to be kept open until the BitmapImage is actually shown.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    return bitmapImage;
}
```