# Get bitmapsource from a picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapsource

I have a picturebox called `picture`
I want to get the image of this picturebox and save it as bitmapsource

```
BitmapSource myPic;
  myPic = picture.Image;
```

But i get this error :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the System.Drawing.Image to a System.Drawing.Bitmap and next convert it to a BitmapSource.

You can pick one of this solutions:
[fast converting Bitmap to BitmapSource wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727343/fast-converting-bitmap-to-bitmapsource-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

use this method:

```
public BitmapSource ImageToBitmapSource(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
        var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image);

        var bitSrc =BitmapToBitmapSource(bitmap);

        bitmap.Dispose();
        bitmap = null;

        return bitSrc;
}

public BitmapSource BitmapToBitmapSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
{
        BitmapSource bitSrc = null;

        var hBitmap = source.GetHbitmap();

        try
        {
            bitSrc = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                hBitmap,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        catch (Win32Exception)
        {
            bitSrc = null;
        }

        return bitSrc;
}
```