# CPU consuming 60% to 70% of the entire CPU power in WPF application using Aforge

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, aforge

I'm running Aforge.net's provided camera test samples on my Dual Core 2.0 GHz laptop with 2 GB RAM. Right now I'm seeing a lot of CPU usage as the application starts displaying visuals from  cameras. It's currently consuming 60% to 70% of the entire CPU power.

Can anyone tell me why it's consuming that much CPU and how can I avoid it? I have to build a similar application which would require  camera vision and I would be using C#.

In this method CPU consuming  more.

```
public void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{

    Bitmap imgforms = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

    h = imgforms.Height;
    w = imgforms.Width;
    //video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imgforms.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    bi.StreamSource = ms;

    bi.EndInit();
    bi.Freeze();

    Dispatcher.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        cam_image.Source = bi;//GetBitmapImage(imgforms);
    }));
    //bi = null;

    // BitmapSource bi = Convert(video);
    if(statusText == "Stop Record")
    {
        // AVIwriter.Quality = 0;
        avwriter.AddFrame(imgforms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its because image processing is very CPU intensive and your laptop is not exactly high end

Comment: You may try [some other method to convert Bitmap to BitmapSource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30727343/1136211).

Comment: @Clemens I already used your method but didn't work for me.